# How to implement proguard in cordova plugin?

Tags: cordova-plugins, proguard, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am creating a plugin in cordova. I want to use progaurd to secure my plugin code. How I can implement progaurd in cordova plugin.

Comment: use can use cordova-plugin-proguard insted of implementing new one https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
proguard.config=proguard-android-optimize.txt
```

in **project.properties** file of your plugin.

Then create and add **proguard-android-optimize.txt** in same folder of **project.properties**
and build with **release** target.

You can find more information about proguard config file [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html).

Comment: how to include project.properties in config.xml of my plugin?

Comment: You can edit cordova project.properties using ant.properties under res/native/android folder on root of cordova project. Or you can make a cordova beforebuild hook can patch (via nodescript or bat) the project.properties file under platform/android cordova folder.